# Facing issue in creating database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, macos, macos-catalina

I am getting below issue in creating a database.

```
Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:78: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/pg-1.3.5/lib/pg.rb:68: warning: The called method `connect' is defined here
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
Couldn't create 'myapp_development' database. Please check your configuration.
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:83:in `rescue in new_client'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:77:in `new_client'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:37:in `postgresql_connection'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:882:in `public_send'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:882:in `new_connection'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:926:in `checkout_new_connection'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:905:in `try_to_checkout_new_connection'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:866:in `acquire_connection'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:588:in `checkout'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:428:in `connection'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:1128:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:327:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:283:in `connection'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.1.5/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:12:in `connection'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.1.5/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:26:in `create'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.1.5/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:133:in `create'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.1.5/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:193:in `block in create_current'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.1.5/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:506:in `block (2 levels) in each_current_configuration'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.1.5/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:503:in `each'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.1.5/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:503:in `block in each_current_configuration'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.1.5/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:502:in `each'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.1.5/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:502:in `each_current_configuration'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.1.5/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:193:in `create_current'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.1.5/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:45:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `load'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `load'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activesupport-6.1.5/lib/active_support/fork_tracker.rb:10:in `block in fork'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activesupport-6.1.5/lib/active_support/fork_tracker.rb:8:in `fork'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activesupport-6.1.5/lib/active_support/fork_tracker.rb:8:in `fork'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activesupport-6.1.5/lib/active_support/fork_tracker.rb:27:in `fork'
-e:1:in `<main>'

Caused by:
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/pg-1.3.5/lib/pg/connection.rb:702:in `connect_start'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/pg-1.3.5/lib/pg/connection.rb:702:in `new'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/pg-1.3.5/lib/pg.rb:69:in `connect'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:78:in `new_client'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:37:in `postgresql_connection'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:882:in `public_send'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:882:in `new_connection'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:926:in `checkout_new_connection'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:905:in `try_to_checkout_new_connection'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:866:in `acquire_connection'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:588:in `checkout'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:428:in `connection'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:1128:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:327:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:283:in `connection'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.1.5/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:12:in `connection'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.1.5/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:26:in `create'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.1.5/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:133:in `create'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.1.5/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:193:in `block in create_current'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.1.5/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:506:in `block (2 levels) in each_current_configuration'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.1.5/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:503:in `each'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.1.5/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:503:in `block in each_current_configuration'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.1.5/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:502:in `each'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.1.5/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:502:in `each_current_configuration'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.1.5/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:193:in `create_current'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activerecord-6.1.5/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:45:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `load'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `load'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/spring-4.0.0/lib/spring/command_wrapper.rb:40:in `call'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/spring-4.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:217:in `block in serve'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activesupport-6.1.5/lib/active_support/fork_tracker.rb:10:in `block in fork'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activesupport-6.1.5/lib/active_support/fork_tracker.rb:8:in `fork'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activesupport-6.1.5/lib/active_support/fork_tracker.rb:8:in `fork'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/activesupport-6.1.5/lib/active_support/fork_tracker.rb:27:in `fork'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/spring-4.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:181:in `serve'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/spring-4.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:144:in `block in run'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/spring-4.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:138:in `loop'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/spring-4.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:138:in `run'
/Users/aniket_tiwari/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/spring-4.0.0/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
```

I have the below configuration in the database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  username: postgres
  password: postgres
```

When I check postgres it is running fine

```
myapp git:(master) ✗ brew services info postgresql@12
postgresql@12 (homebrew.mxcl.postgresql@12)
Running: ✔
Loaded: ✔
Schedulable: ✘
User: root
PID: 15729
```

I have even create the postgres user  and given the permission

```
postgres=# \du
                                     List of roles
   Role name   |                         Attributes                         | Member of
---------------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 aniket_tiwari | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
 postgres      | Superuser                                                  | {}
```

Any help is appreciated?

Postgresql - 12 
Mac OS - Catalina 
Rails - 6

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to run this `lsof -i :5432` to see which process are running in this 5432 port.

Also run `brew services` command to see if status are started and not giving error.